# Library that converts CSS layout to Table layout for e-mail purposes

Tags: linux, library, java

I'm searching for a library that can take HTML and css styles that uses modern block layout attributes, such as `float` etc., and converts that to a table structure.

Unfortunately in this day and age, there are still commonly used mail readers that have very little support for CSS features in their HTML rendering.

The library is preferably a Java library, but any other library or tool that can run on Linux will do as well.